# A solution for a limit

Tags: limits

What do you think about my solution on this limit:
$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x-\sin(2x)}{x^3}=\frac{4}{3}$
We make the substitution $x=3y$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{2x-\sin 2x}{x^{3}}=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{6y-\sin 6y}{27y^{3}}=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{6y-3\sin 2y}{27y^{3}}+\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{4(\sin 2y)^{3}}{27{y^{3}}}$$
We get 
$$l=\frac{3}{27}l+\frac{32}{27}$$
and
$$l=\frac{4}{3}$$

Comment: You did not prove that there was a limit. It is fine apart from that.

Comment: How can you write $\sin 6y=3\sin 2y$?

Comment: @pie314271 He's using the triple angle formula for $\sin$

Comment: (Oh, I thought that the plus sign at the end of the first line was another equals sign for some reason. Sorry.)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lhôpital-rule-or-series-expansion

Answer (score 3):

This looks fine, except that you didn't prove your original limit exists. But this is a rather complicated way to derive this limit, you could have simply used L'Hospital's rule twice, or a simple Taylor expansion in the form $\sin(2x) = 2x - \frac{(2x)^3}{6} + o(x^3)$.